# JQuery Mobile Duplicate Js / Js not work in other page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

I have problem in implementing Javascript on Jquery mobile, everytime I back from a page, the javascript would be duplicated.

Here is the example code:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>JS duplicated page1</title> 

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style-mobile.css">

<script src="js/tes.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="demo-wrapper" data-role="page" data-theme="a" id="page1"> 
        <div class="header" data-role="header" style="position:fixed; background-color:#004165;">
    <div id="div1">
        <span class="right">Click me</span>
        <div id="option"><span style="color:white;">A B C</span></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="separator" style="height:100px;"></div>
    <a href="jsduplicate2.html" data-transition="slide">Go to page2</a>
    </div>
</body>
```

and here is the another page:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>JS duplicated page2</title> 

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style-mobile.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="demo-wrapper" data-role="page" data-theme="a" id="page2"> 

    <div class="header" data-role="header" style="position:fixed; background-color:#004165;">
    <div id="div1">
        <span class="right">Click me</span>
        <div id="option"><span style="color:white;">A B C</span></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="separator" style="height:100px;"></div>
    <a href="jsduplicate1.html" data-transition="slide">Go to page1</a>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the custom JS:

```
$( document ).on( "pageshow", function() {
$(".header #option").toggle('inactive');
$(".header #option").hide();
$(".right").click(function(){   
    $(".header #option").toggle('inactive'); 
    $(".header #option").show();
});
    });
```

Everytime I back from page 2, the toggle run 2 times when I clicked it.

If I initialize the JS only in page1, when navigate to page2, the js didn't work.
Please help ..

Answer (score 0):

Page 2 does not have the script tag, so it was not being loaded. Just add it in.

```
<head>
 <script src="js/tes.js"></script>
</head>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3fbHe/) is working for me.

Comment: If you give the script tag, when back to the page 1, the toggle run 2times (2 animation).